# Validation -- Only when checkbox is checked and Radio button checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

The **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/19eggs/gFvT7/)**

should be pretty explanatory.

There are rows with radio buttons and a check box at the end.

Help 1. What I would like is when ONLY the check box is checked, the values of the checked radio button and along with the value of the textarea and dropdown (if Missing radio button is clicked) to be populated in the text area which is at the bottom?

Help 2. Right now when the radio button is clicked, all the checked radio buttons value are showing. Where am I going wrong ?

To help you understand, from the text area, the data which is separated by ~ and | gets passed over to the next stage when the save all button is clicked. Initially when the page loads the radio buttons are pre-checked depending on the previous page but nothing needs to be populated in the bottom text area.

We use jquery 1.6.4

```
function updateSummary($this){
$this.closest('[id]').find('.r-title, .m-notes-wrapper, .up-arrow, .down-arrow').hide();
var totalRd = $('table').find('input:radio:checked').length;

// Array of clicked items
var clicked = [];

// Set number of selected items
$("#totalRd .rd-count").html(totalRd);

// Show the title and notes next to the radio button
$this.siblings('.r-title, .m-notes-wrapper, .up-arrow, .down-arrow').show();

// Find checked radio buttons that has been clicked
$('table').find("input[type=radio]:checked:enabled").each(function () {
    // Find closest ancestor with an id
    // See if we have a text box, if so use the text
    var $text = $(this).parent().find('textarea.m-notes:visible');
    var missingReason = $(this).parent().find('.reason').val();
    var selectedId = $(this).closest('[id]').attr('id');
    var value = selectedId + "~" + $(this).val();
    if ($text.length)
    {
        value += "~" + missingReason +"~" + $text.val();
    }
    clicked.push(value);
}); //checked

// Display the selected ids 
$("#inputhere").val(clicked.join('|'));
}

// Radio selection changes selected options
$("input:radio").click(function () {
updateSummary($(this));    
 });
 $('textarea.m-notes').bind('keyup', function () {
updateSummary($(this).siblings(':radio'));
});

$('select.reason').change (function () {
updateSummary($(this).siblings(':radio'));
});

$("input:checkbox").change(function(){
updateSummary($(this));    
});
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a condition when updating your textarea :

```
if($('table').find("input[type=checkbox][name='" + $(this).attr('name') + "']").is(':checked')) {
    var $text = $(this).parent().find('textarea.m-notes:visible');
    var missingReason = $(this).parent().find('.reason').val();
    var selectedId = $(this).closest('[id]').attr('id');
    var value = selectedId + "~" + $(this).val();
    if ($text.length)
    {
        value += "~" + missingReason +"~" + $text.val();
    }
    clicked.push(value);
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6f9hs/1/ it does work for me, unless you were asking for something else

Comment: sorry, I did a typo and apparently it still worked fine on chrome for me (but not on firefox). http://jsfiddle.net/6f9hs/3/. Is it better ?

Comment: I had made that change too..saw your typho but it still does not work... :O(

Comment: It should display text on the text area only if the corresponding checkbox is selected. Isn't it what you want ?

Comment: I am so sorry. That is exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much.  However, I noticed 2 things.
1. When missing(eg 1st row) is clicked and nothing in the text area  and or dropdown above it is entered then the values shows as eg 14001290~01~01~CM~~ if only dropdown selected--> 14001290~01~01~CM~1~ if only text area is entered --> 14001290~01~01~CM~~test. I was looking for something like 14001290~01~01~CM or 14001290~01~01~CM~2, or 14001290~01~01~CM~2~test

2. The count Records Selected shows as 3 the moment radio button or check box is selected
Can you use your magic for these two issues ?